# canvas drawImage upscale and then crop

Tags: html, css, canvas, drawimage

Using drawImage, I am trying to do the following with an image that is 1280x720...

- Upscale it to 1920x1080
- Crop it so that only 600x1080 remains from the centre

[image]

I have this so far...

```js
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
            canvas.width=1920;
            canvas.height=1080;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,1920,1080);
        }
        img.src="https://dummyimage.com/1280x720/000/fff";
        //img.src="https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080/000/fff";
```

```css
        body{ background-color: ivory; }
        canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

The upscaling part I have got working but now I am looking at the crop, anyone have an example I can see?

Is there any benefit from cropping first before rescaling?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
> ```

Something like that:

```
x = (img.width - 600) / 2;
y = (img.height - 1080) / 2;
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 600, 1080, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
```

but check for the destination area parameters depending on what exactly you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

### Clip image to fit canvas

The canvas will clip the image for you.

By default all rendering has a clip region set to the canvas size. Because the clip is performed regardless of the size of the content (all content must be checked against the clip region and is done in hardware (GPU)) rendering the full image is slightly quicker than rendering a portion of the image.

```
 ctx.drawImage(image,x,y); // is the quicker function
 ctx.drawImage(image,ix,iy,iw,ih,x,y,w,h); // the slower function
```

*Note; This is not true when the rendered visible destination content is significantly smaller than the image source*

Thus to render the image cropped to a smaller canvas you only need to find the center and then render the image at half its size away from that center.

```
ctx.drawImage(
    image,      // image to render
    (ctx.canvas.width - image.width) / 2,  // center sub half image width
    (ctx.canvas.height - image.height) / 2 // center sub half image height
);
```

If you need to up scale first the following will render any size image to fit 1080 height.

```
const imgW = 1920;
const imgH = 1080;
ctx.drawImage(
    image,      // image to render
    (ctx.canvas.width - imgW) / 2,  // center sub half image display width
    (ctx.canvas.height - imgH) / 2,  // center sub half image display height
    imgW, imgH
);
```

### Crop image

If you wish to save memory and crop the image you use a canvas to hold the cropped image.

```
function cropImageCenter(image,w,h){
    const c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image,(w - image.width) / 2, (h - image.height) / 2);
    return c;
}

var img = new Image;
img.src = "imageURL1280by720.jpg";
img.onload = () => { 
     img = cropImageCenter(img, 600, 1080); 
     ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); /// render cropped image on to canvas
};
```

Or to upscale and crop

```
function scaleCropToHeight(image,w,h){
    const c = document.createElement("canvas");
    c.width = w;
    c.height = h;
    const scale = h / image.height;
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        (w - image.width * scale) / 2, 
        (h - image.height * scale) / 2,
        image.width * scale,
        image.height * scale
    );
    return c;
}

var img = new Image;
img.src = "imageURL1920by1080.jpg";
img.onload = () => { 
     img = scaleCropToHeight(img, 600, 1080);
     ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); /// render cropped image on to canvas
};
```